# Default behavior of dependsOnMethods is unexpected

Tags: testng

TestNG is unable to dig up after First level on dependsOnMethods.
TestNG version:6.11
dependsOnMethods of testNg is not working properly.

```
 @Test
                            public void test1(){
                                System.out.println("test1");
                            }
                            @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test1"})
                            public void test2(){
                                System.out.println("test2");
                            }
                            @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test2"})
                            public void test3(){
                                System.out.println("test3");
                            }
                            @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test3"})
                            public void test4(){
                                System.out.println("test4");
                            }
                            @Test(dependsOnMethods={"test4"})
                            public void test5(){
                                System.out.println("test5");
                            }
```

when I ran testcase test5 it show me below result

```
PASSED: test1


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: How are you running your tests ? This is a very basic use case for TestNG. So if its broken, I would like to dig in to find out what happened. Can you please help add more information here ?

Comment: It seems there is some bug in latest version of TestNG. I don't know what's the problem with latest version but I tried with the TestNG version 6.9.13.6 and its working fine for me.

Comment: I doubt if that's the case. There are a lot of unit tests around this. Can you please let me know how you are running your tests ? It would be good if you could please help call out the steps that you follow to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to downgrade your TestNg version to 6.9.13.6